# reloadRowsAtIndexPaths does not change constraints of UItableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, constraints

This is my code. I set height constraint conditionally. when i reload whole table it works good but not does not work with reloadRowsAtIndexPaths

```
id superView = btn.superview.superview;
NSIndexPath *indexpath = [tbl indexPathForCell:superView];
AddYardTicketItemCell *cell = [tbl cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexpath];
if (cell.constantViewHeight.constant == 0) {
    cell.constantViewHeight.constant = 130;        
}
else
{
cell.constantViewHeight.constant = 0;         
}
[cell layoutIfNeeded];
[tbl reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexpath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

Comment: No need to set constraints for cell height use `self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0;` to adjust height of cell

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changed height of one cell requires the `tableView` to move all the following cells. So I guess that's why `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` did not work for you. Try to change:

```
[tbl reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexpath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

to:

```
[tbl beginUpdates];
[tbl setNeedsDisplay];
[tbl endUpdates];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the delegate method heightForRowAtIndexPath instead of supplying the height in cellForRowAtIndexPath..Reload will work. That's the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

While designing cell in storyboard apply all constraints properly i.e. apply all required constrains: top, bottom, left and right so that height of cell can be calculated automatically depending on its content.

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension; 
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0;
```